# How can I create a column based on a condition in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy

I need to create a new column in Pandas by parsing the values in an existing column. This is the function I've created, which works prefectly with other operators like `==`:

```
def parse_trust_name(row):
    if row["trust"].str.contains('OLYMPIA'):
        val = 'Olympia Trust Company'
    else:
        val = 'Open Account'
    return val
```

I get the following error message when I run it: `'str' object has no attribute 'str'`

I am running the following code to apply the function: `master_df["trust_new"] = master_df.apply(parse_trust_name, axis=1)`

I thought about using np.where but I don't know how to make it conditional.

How can I fix this function?

Comment: master_df["trust_new"] = ['Olympia Trust Company' if 'OLYMPIA' in i else 'Open Account' for i in master_df["trust"]]

Answer (score 1):

See the comment for a one line solution. To fix your function, you'll need to rewrite that if statement.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out

```
def parse_trust_name_test(row):
    if 'OLYMPIA' in row["trust"]:
        return 'Olympia Trust Company'
    else:
        return 'Open Account'
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).